# web-scraping Newegg - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently coding in python using BS4 to get the html code from the webpage. Basically I started extracting the prices and names from the website, and it was working. Then the next thing I know it just stops working even though I didn't change the code at all.Currently I am just wondering is there a way to fix this and exactly what happened. I am novice when it comes to these things and am just trying to improve my coding skills by working on this little project of mine that scrapes the price and model of the GPUs on newegg. I did look up and tried to find the answer before hand.... but like I said I am a novice and probably do not know the terminology (I self taught myself).
Here is my code if you would like to see what I have done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas
import requests,re

#webscrape prices off of newegg
r_newegg=requests.get(URL GOES HERE)
c_newegg=r_newegg.content

soup_newegg=BeautifulSoup(c_newegg,"html.parser")
print(soup_newegg)
newegg_price=soup_newegg.find_all("div",{"class":"item-action"})
#newegg_price[0].find("span").next_sibling.next_sibling.text ## this is the way to find the price
newegg_name=soup_newegg.find_all("a",{"class":"item-title"})
print(newegg_name.find("a").text)
print(newegg_name[0].find("a"))
newegg=[]

for price,name in zip(newegg_price,newegg_name):#don't forget to use zip to iterate through two lists
    d={}
    try:
        d["Price"]=price.find("span").next_sibling.next_sibling.text
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you provide url? First things to check: 1. Is my IP / bot banned, 2. Did the website changed ?

Comment: [link]https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&N=100007709%2050001419%2050001315%2050001402%2050001312%2050001669%2050012150%2050001561%2050001314%2050001471%20600566292%20600566291%20600565504%20601201888%20601204369%20601210955%20601203793%204814%20601296707&IsNodeId=1&cm_sp=Cat_video-Cards_1-_-Visnav-_-Gaming-Video-Cards_1

Comment: Also how would u check if your IP or bot banned bc I can still access the webpage thanks in advance

Comment: Scraping the page stops working after a few times accessing the page because the website uses [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/). You can check if your IP or bot gets banned by try to open your link when your code stops working. It stopped working for me and I got this [reCaptcha page](http://i.imgur.com/dtDXOjg.png).

Answer (score 3):

Scraping the page stops working after a few times accessing the page because the website uses [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/).

When web-scraping stops working, you can verify this by manually opening the URL in a browser, which may reveal a reCaptcha bot warning similar to this:
[image]
However, after accessing the page manually in a web-browser (and possibly needing to check-mark the "I am not a robot" form), you should be able to run your code again and scrape the page.

As for scraping the data from the page, and retrieving the item names and prices, this code should do the job. I added some string output numbering and formatting for ease of reading the results:

```
items = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'item-container'})

names = []
prices = []

for item in items:
    names.append(item.find('a', {'class': "item-title"}).text.strip('\n').strip(' ').strip('\n'))
    for price in item.find_all('li', {'class': 'price-current'}):
        prices.append(''.join([price.strong.text.strip(), price.sup.text.strip()]))

items_prices = zip(prices, names)

for n, (price, item) in enumerate(items_prices):
    print 'Item #{n}: {p} : {i}'.format(n=n+1, p=price, i=item)
```

output:

```
Item #1: 139.99 : EVGA GeForce GTX 1050 FTW GAMING ACX 3.0, 02G-P4-6157-KR, 2GB GDDR5, DX12 OSD Support (PXOC)
Item #2: 699.99 : GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1080 Ti DirectX 12 GV-N108TGAMING OC-11GD 11GB 352-Bit GDDR5X PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Card
Item #3: 119.99 : GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1050 DirectX 12 GV-N1050OC-2GD 2GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Card
Item #4: 159.99 : GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1050 Ti DirectX 12 GV-N105TWF2OC-4GD 4GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Card
Item #5: 139.99 : GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1050 Ti DirectX 12 GV-N105TD5-4GD 4GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Cards
Item #6: 809.99 : EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti SC2 HYBRID GAMING, 11G-P4-6598-KR, 11GB GDDR5X, HYBRID & LED, iCX Technology - 9 Thermal Sensors
...
Item #35: 109.99 : ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1050 DirectX 12 ZT-P10500A-10L 2GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready Video Card
Item #36: 719.99 : ASUS GeForce GTX 1080 Ti DirectX 12 TURBO-GTX1080TI-11G 11GB 352-Bit GDDR5X PCI Express 3.0 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome answer. Very kind of you to share this knowledge.